# swift bridging got whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift

I am bridging an Obj-C pdf reader into my book reader.
I imported to my bridging-header.h:

```
#import "ReaderDemoController.h"
```

after that on my pdfreader.swift, I import all needed framework and put class like this:

```
class PDFReader: ReaderDemoController, ReaderViewControllerDelegate
```

on pdfreader.swift viewdidload, I called readerdemocontroller like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    //super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNavigationBar()
    var instanceOfCustomObject: ReaderDemoController = ReaderDemoController()
    instanceOfCustomObject.viewDidLoad()   
}
```

but when I run I got error log like this:

```
<Reader1ViewController: 0x7fb2e3866a60> on <ReaderDemoController: 0x7fb2e39334f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Reader1ViewController called when success called ReaderDemoController, all already included in ReaderViewControllerDelegate

What is the mean of whose view is not in the window hierarchy? Which is the correct bridging code to show ReaderDemoController inside PDFReader class in viewdidload?

regards.